# Tabs в карточке товаров на сайте WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

Есть сайт на WordPress с модулем интернет-магазина WooCommerce и на нем шаблон WoodMart.

Сейчас отображается так (скрин во вложении)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно поменять tab местами: Описание, Характеристики, Доставка и оплата, Как выбрать размер, Отзывы.

Код, отображаемый на странице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот код ёё формирования:

```
    <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper tabs-layout-<?php echo esc_attr( $tabs_layout ); ?>">
    <ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
        <?php foreach ( $product_tabs as $key => $product_tab ) : ?>
            <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>_tab <?php echo $tab_count === 0 ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $product_tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php $tab_count++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php foreach ( $product_tabs as $key => $product_tab ) : ?>
        <div class="woodmart-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" class="woodmart-accordion-title tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?> <?php echo $content_count === 0 ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $product_tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
            <div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?> panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                <div class="wc-tab-inner 
                <?php
                if ( $scroll ) {
                    echo 'woodmart-scroll';}
                ?>
                ">
                    <div class="<?php echo true == $scroll ? 'woodmart-scroll-content' : ''; ?>">
                        <?php call_user_func( $product_tab['callback'], $key, $product_tab ); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $content_count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_tabs' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Что за версия WoodMart? В 3.4.0 код несколько иной.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, добрый день. Версия WoodMart 5.3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом, в любой теме под WooCommerce можно поменять порядок вкладок. Добавьте такой код в `functions.php` вашей дочерней темы:

```
/**
 * Filter WooCommerce product tabs.
 *
 * @param array $tabs Tabs.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $new_tabs['reviews']     = $tabs['reviews'];
    $new_tabs['description'] = $tabs['description'];

    return $new_tabs;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'my_woocommerce_product_tabs', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

В примере создаётся новый массив вкладок и изменяется их порядок: сначала reviews, затем descriptions.

У вас вкладок больше, ключи массива вкладок вы можете узнать, вставив `var_dump( $tabs )` в начало функции.

Comment: Я вам написал, читайте внимательно: **добавьте** код в `functions.php` вашей **дочерней темы**. О дочерних темах: https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html

Comment: Чтобы узнать массив, так надо?  
function my_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {var_dump( $tabs );
    $new_tabs['reviews']     = $tabs['reviews'];
    $new_tabs['description'] = $tabs['description'];

    return $new_tabs;
}

Comment: **внутрь** надо вставить, после строчки `function my_woocommerce_product_tabs( $tabs ) {`

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Получилось :)